# Unsure why: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 201

Tags: apex, soql, limitexception

I am running into the infamous System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 201 error, but I am really not sure why. In this class I am attempting to get a JSON object from a URL and then use it to create new contacts in our system. In my class I need to continue to call makeHttpCall until next_url is returned null to get the entire JSON object. Once that is done I want to call processData to insert the new contacts.

I am attempting to query a list from a map and am hitting the limit when I do so.

Line 102 - Contact[] conList = [SELECT ID, Email, Zenefits_Id__c FROM Contact WHERE Zenefits_Id__c IN : newEmployeeMap.keySet() LIMIT 200];

But I am also receiving the error from...

line line 12 where I call processData();

Here is my code for reference. I have removed the initial URL as well as the Bearer token for security purposes.

```
public class zenefitsEmployeeSync implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
  public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      makeCallout();
  }
  
  @future(callout = true)
  public static void makeCallout() {
      string url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      do {
          url = makeHttpCall(url);
      } while(url != null);
    processData();
  }
  
  static list<object> newEmployees = new list<object>();
  static map<String,Id> dataAttributes = new Map<string,Id>();
  static List<Object> account = new List<Object>();
  static {
      for (account a : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name Like 'LLC%' LIMIT 1]) {
          dataAttributes.put('accountId',a.Id);
      }
  }
  
  static List<Object> Calendar = new List<Object>();
  static {
      for (pse__Work_Calendar__c workCal : [SELECT name, ID FROM pse__Work_Calendar__c WHERE Name Like 'US Full-Time 8x5%' LIMIT 1]) {
          dataAttributes.put('workcalId',workCal.Id);
      }
  }
  
      public static String makeHttpCall(String url) {
      string nextUrl;
      Http http = new Http();
      HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
      request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxx');
      request.setEndpoint(url);
      request.setMethod('GET');
      HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
      // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
      if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) { 
          // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of posts.
          Map<String, Object> wrapper = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
          if (wrapper.containsKey('data')) {
              Map<String, Object> wrapper2 = (Map<String, Object>) wrapper.get('data');
              if (wrapper2.containsKey('data')) {
                  nextUrl = (String) wrapper2.get('next_url');
                  newEmployees.addAll((List<Object>)wrapper2.get('data'));
                  system.debug('New Employees Sze ' + newEmployees.size());
              }
          }
      }
      return nextUrl;
  }
  
  public static void processData() {
      List<contact> employeesToInsert = new List<contact> ();
      Map<String,map<String, Object>> employeeMap = new Map<String,map<String, Object>>();
      
      for (Object LevvelEmployee : newEmployees) {
          Map<string,object> employees = (Map<string,object>)LevvelEmployee ;
          Map<String,map<String, Object>> newEmployeeMap  = new Map<String,map<String, Object>>(); 
          Map<String, Object> managerWrapper = (Map<String, Object>) Employees.get('manager');
          Map<String, Object> DepartmentWrapper = (Map<String, Object>) Employees.get('department');
          Map<String,Object> empValues = new Map<String,Object>();
                          
          if( (Employees.get('status') == 'active')&&( managerWrapper.get('url') != NULL)){

          String ZenefitsLastName = (String) Employees.get('last_name');
          empValues.put('LastName',Employees.get('last_name'));
          String ZenefitsFirstName = (String) Employees.get('first_name');
          empValues.put('FirstName',Employees.get('first_name'));
          String ZenefitseEmployeeId = (String) Employees.get('id');
          empValues.put('ZenefitseEmployeeId',Employees.get('id'));
          String ZenefitsEmail = (String) Employees.get('work_email');
          empValues.put('ZenefitsEmail',Employees.get('work_email'));
          String Status = (String) Employees.get('status');
          empValues.put('Status',Employees.get('status'));
          String title = (String) Employees.get('title');
          empValues.put('title',Employees.get('title'));
          String phoneNumber = (string) employees.get('work_phone');
          empValues.put('phoneNumber',Employees.get('work_phone'));
          string managerUrl = (string) managerWrapper.get('url');
          empValues.put('managerUrl',managerWrapper.get('url')); 
          system.debug('managerURL ' + managerWrapper.get('url')); 
          string managerId = managerUrl.substring(managerUrl.length() - 7, managerUrl.length() - 0);
          empValues.put('managerId',managerId);
          string alias = ZenefitsFirstName.substring(0,1) + ZenefitsLastName.substring(0,3);
          system.debug('alias ' + alias);
          empValues.put('alias', alias);
                          
          string department = (string) departmentWrapper.get('url');
          empValues.put('department',departmentWrapper.get('url'));
                        
          String departmentURL = department.substring(department.length() - 6, department.length() - 0);
          empValues.put('departmentURL',departmentURL);
          system.debug('department url ' + departmentURL);
                          
          newEmployeeMap.put(ZenefitseEmployeeId, empValues);
          system.debug('newEmployeeMap ' + newEmployeeMap);
                          
          //now query the list of contacts in the system so we can remove them and only insert new Employees
          Contact[] conList = [SELECT ID, Email, Zenefits_Id__c FROM Contact WHERE Zenefits_Id__c IN : newEmployeeMap.keySet() LIMIT 200];
          system.debug('conList ' + conList);
          for(Contact con1 : conList) 
          {
            //remove the Employees that already exist in the system
              newEmployeeMap.remove(con1.Zenefits_Id__c); //remove existing contacts
              system.debug('newEmployeeMap ' + newEmployeeMap);
          }
                  
          for(String zId: newEmployeeMap.keyset()) 
          {
            map<String,Object> currMap = newEmployeeMap.get(zId);
              system.debug('currMap' + currMap); 

              //create a contact record for the new resource
              Contact con = new Contact();
              con.Zenefits_Id__c = (string)currMap.get('ZenefitseEmployeeId');
              con.Lastname  = (string)currMap.get('LastName');
              con.FirstName = (string)currMap.get('FirstName');
              con.Email = (string)currMap.get('ZenefitsEmail');
              con.Title = (string)currMap.get('title');
              con.Manager_Zenefits_ID__c = (string)currMap.get('managerId');
              con.Phone = (string)currMap.get('phoneNumber');
              con.pse__Start_Date__c = system.today();
              con.pse__Is_Resource__c = true; 
              con.pse__Is_Resource_Active__c = true;
              con.AccountId = (String)dataAttributes.get('accountId');
              con.pse__Work_Calendar__c = (String)dataAttributes.get('workcalId');
              con.pse__Level__c = 'Consultant';
              con.pse__Resource_Role__c = 'Analyst';
              con.recordTypeId = '0121N0000012es9QAA';
              con.zenefits_department_id__c = departmentURL;
              con.alias__c = (String)currmap.get('alias');

              employeesToInsert.add(con);
              system.debug('contacts to update ' + employeesToInsert.size());
              }      
          }
      upsert employeesToInsert;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have SOQL in for loop `Contact[] conList = [SELECT ID, Email, Zenefits_Id__c FROM Contact WHERE Zenefits_Id__c IN : newEmployeeMap.keySet() LIMIT 200];`.May be your `newEmployees` is more. You can query this on top and use it inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have SOQL in for loop.

```
Contact[] conList = [SELECT ID, Email, Zenefits_Id__c FROM Contact WHERE Zenefits_Id__c IN : newEmployeeMap.keySet() LIMIT 200];
```

May be your newEmployees is more. You can query this on top and use it inside.

As you are using this `IN : newEmployeeMap.keySet()` as your filter criteria and that can be done outside loop.